# Bulk renaming files with multiple rules in bash

Tags: bash

What's the most efficient way to rename all files that match `ls *.abc` by applying three rules:

1. the last 10 characters of a basename should be removed (i.e. `mv "he'llo\"world-FGhjklmno.abc" "helloworld.abc"`)
2. all double quotes from the ***original filename*** should be **escaped** to avoid bash syntax error
3. all single and double quotes should be **removed** from the ***new filename***

Examples for each rule:

1. e.g. original filename: `helloworld-FGhjklmno.abc`, generated bash command: `mv "helloworld-FGhjklmno.abc" "helloworld.abc"`
2. e.g. original filename: `he"lloworld-MGnjElGnX.abc`, generated bash command: `mv "he\"lloworld-MGnjElGnX.abc" "helloworld.abc"`
3. e.g. original filename: `he"l'loworld-YaFjPdd36.abc`, generated bash command: `mv "he\"l'loworld-YaFjPdd36.abc" "helloworld.abc"`

I tried with the following so far:

```
ls *.abc 2>/dev/null | awk -F. '{printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s.abc\"\n",$0,substr($0,1,length($0)-length($NF)-13),$NF ;}' | bash
```

But that won't include the second and the third rule:

I tried to replace `%s` with `%q`, but it didn't work. I also tried to pipe **substr** to **sed -e 's|["'\'`']||g'** but it didn't work either.

Besides, not sure how to treat backticks ` if they appear in filenames, to avoid issues during bulk renaming of files...

Comment: You say two rules, but list 3. Also, in rule 2, you escape double quotes (but they are valid in file names), and in 3, you remove them. Can you give examples for each rule?

Comment: @choroba: Yes, there are 3 rules in total.  I just edited my question. In rule 2 I need to escape doublequotes, since the filename is used in mv "filename_old" "filename_new", so filename_old should have doublequotes escaped to avoid syntax error in bash. I will edit my question further with some examples for each rule...

Comment: This will be far much simpler with a sample input and expected output

Comment: @Gilles Quenot: I just provided some examples in my question.

Comment: `original filename should be escaped to avoid bash syntax error` that's not optimal. Instead create a command chain that will work with any characters in filenames. `ls *.abc` [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks for heads up, this definitely shed some new light for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Parameter Expansion and `mv` for external tools.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *.abc; do
  filename=${f%-*}
  filename=${filename//\"}
  filename=${filename//\'}
  extension=${f##*.}
  echo mv -v "$f" "$filename.$extension"
done
```

---

To remove the last 10 strings from the basename, would be something like.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *.abc; do
  filename=${f%.*}
  last_ten=${filename:(-10)}
  filename=${filename%"$last_ten"*}
  filename=${filename//\"}
  filename=${filename//\'}
  extension=${f##*.}
  echo mv -v "$f" "$filename.$extension"
done
```

- Remove the `echo` if you think that the output is correct.

Comment: It won't work for files that don't contain dashes and for files that have more than one dash in their filenames, i.e. `i - am - a - filename-Rfta81MNT.abc`.

Comment: Right, it will not, but it will work on your example input, which my answer was based upon.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
rename -n 's/\p{P}+//g; s/.*/substr($&, 0, 10) . ".abc"/e' *.abc
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: I just installed `rename` and ran `rename -n 's/\p{P}+//g; s/.*/substr($&, 0, 10) . ".abc"/e' *.abc` in my test folder with 5 abc files with their basenames longer than 10 characters, but the command doesn't return/display anything?

Comment: How did you installed it, and which distro ? As explained in my answer, did you ran `file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"` ?

Comment: I installed it via AUR in my Manjaro: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rename 
`file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"` outputs `/usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=cede643cd510a86d763c2e1ed7b5acc9bd5015c2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`

Comment: OK, so you don't read my answer. Should not be ELF. IIRC, it's `prename` for archlinux

Comment: I did. There's no `prename`. The closest is `gprename`? http://gprename.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try AUR repository

Comment: I did a full search for all repositories. There's no prename in AUR.

Comment: So it's in the official repository. Search `perl rename` (default on many distros). I explained how to download it as a standalone script too

Comment: Thanks, `perl-rename` it is: https://metacpan.org/release/PEDERST/rename-1.9